# Checkmate in 7 moves?

Tags: checkmate, positional-play

In the below chess position, the chess.com computer analysis says that there is a checkmate in 7 moves for Black, but I can't find the way. Can you help me find the solution? White's last move was Rxe7, which chess.com says is a blunder, allowing for the mate in 7.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You posted a different position after my comment and PhishMaster's answer.

As for the new position, yes it is mate in 7 starting with Rxc1+.

Possible continuations are:

1. Kd2 Rc2+ 2. Ke1 (if 2. Ke3 Re2++; if 2. Kd1 Nf3+ 3. Rd7 Rxd7++) Nf3+ 4. Rxf3 Bxf3 (threat is Rd1++) 5. Re8+ Rxe8 6. Kf1 Bg2+ 7. Kg1 Re1++
2. Kf2 Rc2+ 2. Kg1 (if 2. Ke1 or Ke3 see the other line above) Nf3+ 3. Rxf3 (3. Kh1 Rxh2++) Rd1+ 4. Rf1 Rg2+ 5. Kh1 Rxf1++

As I wrote above the mating patterns are not particularly pretty. It boils down (in the longer lines) to mating with two rooks, one on the second and one on the first rank. Also it is more like a mate in 5 as some of the moves are just white sacrificing a rook to prolong the mate.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution to your question, since you changed the position, with the lines being on a board.

```
   [FEN "3r2k1/p3Rp1p/6p1/8/3nbP2/P1r3P1/P6P/2B1KR2 b - - 0 1"]

    1... Rxc1+ 2. Kd2 (2. Kf2 Rc2+ 3. Ke1 Nf3+ 4. Rxf3 Bxf3 5. Re8+ Rxe8+ 6. Kf1 Ree2 7. a4 Rc1#) 2... Rc2+ 3. Ke1 (3. Kd1 Nf3+ 4. Rd7 Rxd7#) 3... Nf3+ 4. Rxf3 Bxf3 5. Re8+ Rxe8+ 6. Kf1 Bg2+ 7. Kg1 Re1#
```

Comment: Since you changed the position, here are some lines on a board.